# How to flat xml to one line in c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How to flat xml to one line in c# code ?

Before:

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

After:

```
<CATALOG><CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE><ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>....
```

Comment: We need more details: where is this XML coming from? You want that "flat" result stored in a file? Variable?

Comment: You have this xml in a C# string and want to change the value? OR, You have written this multiline xml in Visual Studio and want to make it one line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're able to use LINQ to XML, and the XML is currently in a file:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
document.Save("test2.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: Additional info: in order to use LINQ to XML add "System.Xml.Linq" assemblies reference to project. First line should be "using System.Xml.Linq;".

Answer (score 7):

If you cant use LINQ to XML, you can:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml("Xml as string");  or xmlDoc.Load(filepath)
xmlDoc.InnerXml -- this should return one liner
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have the XML in a string:

```
xml.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")
```

Comment: This won't get rid of the spaces from the indentation.

Answer (score 4):

I know, that this is old question, but it helped me to find XDocument.ToString()

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
// Flat one line XML
string s = doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

[Check SaveOptions documentaion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are working with and what output you need...
John Skeet's answer works if reading and writing to files.
Aleksej Vasinov's answer works if you want xml without the xml declaration.

If you simply want the xml in a string, but want the entire structure of the xml, including the declaration, ie..

```
<?xml version "1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>   <-- This is the declaration ->
<TheRestOfTheXml />
```

.. use a StringWriter...

```
XDocument doc = GetTheXml(); // op's xml
var wr = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(wr, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
var s = wr.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```